# Isomorphic graphs definition, understanding of the application of permutation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-isomorphism, directed-graphs, similar-matrices, permutation-matrices

I was thinking about the definition for two graphs being *isomorphic:*

Basically considering two graphs $\mathcal{G}, \, \mathcal{S}$ they are known to be *isomorphic* if they are essentially *identical* in terms of their structure. In other words, denoting $A_{\mathcal{G}}, \, A_{\mathcal{S}}$ we have that

$$A_{\mathcal{S}} = PA_{\mathcal{G}}P^T$$

for some permutation matrix $P$.

This is essentially clear but I don't understand well why we would express the above thing that way, what is the meaning of applying the operation $P (\cdot)P^T$. What is the sense of applying $P$ to $A_{\mathcal{G}}$ and then applying again $P^T$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $P$ represents a permutation $\pi\colon \{1,\ldots,n\}\to \{1,\ldots,n\} $ and also that $P^T=P^{-1}$. If $\pi$ is the permutation that corresponds to how the vertices of $\mathcal G$ are identified with those of $\mathcal S$, then $PA_{\mathcal G}P^{T}$ maps some base vector $e_{\pi(k)}$ to $e_k$, then to the sum of all neighbours $e_{j_1},\ldots,e_{j_d}$ of $e_k$, and finally to the sum of all neigbours $e_{\pi(j_1)},\ldots,e_{\pi(j_d)}$ of $e_{\pi(k)}$, as desired.

Comment: Thank you actually I observed that for any matrix $A$ one has $A_{ij} = e_i^TAe_j$ and $Pe_i = e_{\pi(i)}$ hence the permuted i,j entry of A is just $(Pe_i)^T A (Pe_j)$